# Repeating code for N cases error

Tags: c++

This is a problem from SPOJ that takes a string "index text" and deletes text[index], i got it working fine without looping, but the problem requires looping the whole code for N cases.
once i add the code require for looping

```
int N;cin >> N;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
//code
}
```

the console print a lot of weird characters and then it goes not responding

Problem description for more info : http://www.spoj.com/problems/GNY07A/

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;cin >> N;  // for looping N case
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        string s;int iterate = 1;
        getline(cin, s);

        // converts index part to an int
        string index = s.substr(0,1);
        int I = atoi(index.c_str());

        // deleting index from text
        char temp[s.length()-2];int K = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(i != I+1){
                temp[K]=s[i];
                K++;
            }
        }

        // replacing index with iteration number(required)
        string c;
        stringstream out;
        out << iterate;
        c = out.str();
        iterate++;
        temp[0] = c[0];

        // output
        for(int i = 0; i != s.length()-1; i++)
        {
            cout << temp[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline(cin, s);` after formatting input of `N` is only going to consume the rest of the line `N` appeared on, right? Pretty sure you want to eat the rest of that first line *prior* to entering your loop. As far as the rest of the code is concerned, checking your IO for success wouldn't hurt, and `char temp[s.length()-2]` isn't standard C++; suggest you use a `std::vector`.

Comment: So how would i get the input for s considering it must have a space

Comment: Consume the rest of the line containing the test numbers prior to starting the main line-processing loop. `        `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` is one such way. Do that after you extract `N` and before you start the loop. And *check your io for failures*.

Comment: The linked duplicate has different loop logic, but the premise is the same. formatted extraction of the number prior to the line-loop is not consuming the remainder of the initial line (the one with the number) through eoln. The snippet i posted earlier is one such way to do that. Best of luck.